# Daniel 7:14 douleuō vs. latreuō?

Tags: greek, daniel

I have found two different renderings of פְלַח (*pelach*) at Daniel 7:14 in the LXX. One is [δουλεύω](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g1398/lxx/lxx/27-1/#lexResults) (*douleuō*) and the other is [λατρεύω](https://biblehub.com/sepd/daniel/7.htm) (*latreuō*)

Are Blueletterbible and Biblehub citing different source texts for the LXX?

Can anyone shed some light on this? I'd like to know if there is a consensus as to which Greek word is preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the simple facts for the LXX text of Daniel 7:14:

**Breton's LXX**: (as per [Ellopos](https://www.ellopos.net/elpenor/greek-texts/septuagint/chapter.asp?book=50&page=7))

> καὶ αὐτῷ ἐδόθη ἡ ἀρχὴ καὶ ἡ τιμὴ καὶ ἡ βασιλεία, καὶ πάντες οἱ **λαοί**,
> φυλαί, γλῶσσαι αὐτῷ **δουλεύσουσιν**· ἡ ἐξουσία αὐτοῦ ἐξουσία αἰώνιος,
> ἥτις οὐ παρελεύσεται, καὶ ἡ βασιλεία αὐτοῦ οὐ διαφθαρήσεται. = And to
> him was given the dominion, and the honour, and the kingdom; and all
> nations, tribes, and languages, shall **serve** him: his dominion is an
> everlasting dominion, which shall not pass away, and his kingdom shall
> not be destroyed.

**Swete's LXX**: (as per [BibleHub](https://biblehub.com/multi/daniel/7-14.htm))

> καὶ ἐδόθη αὐτῷ **ἐξουσία** καὶ τιμὴ **βασιλική**, καὶ πάντα τὰ **ἔθνη** τῆς γῆς
> κατὰ γένη καὶ πᾶσα δόξα αὐτῷ **λατρεύουσα**· καὶ ἡ ἐξουσία αὐτοῦ
> ἐξουσία αἰώνιος ἥτις οὐ μὴ ἀρθῇ, καὶ ἡ βασιλεία αὐτοῦ, ἥτις οὐ μὴ
> φθαρῇ. = And to him was given authority and royal honor, and all the nations
> of the earth; and all races shall bring glory and **serve** him:
> his authority is everlasting which shall not pass away,
> and his kingdom shall not be destroyed.

I could also quote Rahlfs LXX and Theodoton's LXX which are all a little different again.  I have highlighted the differences between the above two - more could be pointed out.

The point is that the LXX is far from monolithic and far from uniform.  Numerous manuscripts exist that all have a slightly different text.  Some of these differences are not even translatable and others are minor.  See Rahlfs LXX (pub: Deutsche Bibelgesellschaft) which lists some of the major MSS variations.

Note that the above difference makes little difference to the main sense and thrust of the passage.

Comment: Are these variant texts of LXX found in solitary renderings of the OT or are they found attached to other manuscripts ? I know (having seen the original in the British Museum) that Codex Alexandrinus came with a version of LXX but I do not know what variant. Up-voted +1.

Comment: @NigelJ - good question.  Some of the major MSS variants are listed in Rahlfs LXX - I will add a note to the answer to mention this.

Comment: Theodotion's version eliminates the conflict of a Being (Son of Man) receiving sacred worship service other than God. If we understand that Theodotion reinterpreted the text of the ancient Septuagint, as he did with the word virgin for youth in Isaiah 7:14, by being a Jewish proselyte, we understand that at that time the Jewish world was not prepared to accept another Divine Being being worshiped sacred.

Comment: Peal of the פלח : Ezr. 7:24, Dan. 3:12, 14, 17f, 28; Dan. 6:17, 21; Dan. 7:14, 27. Note the verse: Daniel 3:28: ebuchadnezzar exclaimed,[av] “Praised be the God of Shadrach, Meshach, and Abednego, who has sent forth his angel[aw] and has rescued his servants who trusted in him, ignoring[ax] the edict of the king and giving up their bodies rather than[ay] serve or pay homage to any god other than their God!